Redirecting to "Google.com" when trying to Google Login in React Native Expo App
This is what my app.config.js looks like. Both IOS and Android have different package names because my android app got suspended, and I had to rename it. I have a feeling It's because the bundle name is different, any work around this? Or is something else breaking it. Please let me know what's wrong :'(
This is happening to only android devices. I'm using React Native Expo + Firebase for Auth
"slug": "iosBundle2023",
"scheme": "iosBundle2023",
...
"ios": {    
  "bundleIdentifier": "com.myMobileApp.iosBundle2023",    
  "infoPlist": {
        "CFBundleDisplayName": "iosBundle2023"
      },
    ...
    },
"android": {
      "package": "com.myMobileApp.androidBundleNew",
    ...
    }
}

Here what my code looks like.
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google'
import {  GoogleAuthProvider
  signInWithCredential
} from 'firebase/auth'

    const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
        webClientId: Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.GOOGLE_WEB_ID,
        clientId: Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        iosClientId: Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.GOOGLE_IOS_ID,
        androidClientId: Constants.expoConfig?.extra?.GOOGLE_ANDROID_ID,
        scopes: ["profile", "email"]
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        if (response?.type === 'success') {
            fetchUserInfo(response.authentication.accessToken)
        }      
    }, [response])

    async function fetchUserInfo(token) {
        
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null, token)
        signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                // User is signed in with Firebase, you can access user data here
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // Handle any errors that occur during sign-in
             
            })
    }

